# New tab code target = "_blank" not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Iam using following code in Layout page for advertisement,

```
 <div class="item active" onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("adv1", "Advertisement", new { target = "_blank" }) + "'");">
                <img src="~/Images/adv1.png" alt="1">
          </div>
```

but in click event its not open new tabe..whats the change in code to open new tab ?

Comment: Debug step: inspect the generated HTML in the browser of that div - is that what you expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up creating a link and creating a URL. Currently you are just creating a URL with a querystring entry called `target`, something like '/Advertsement/adv/?target=_blank'. This won't open a new tab.

Instead you should create an `a` link tag with a `target` attribute:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("adv1", "Advertisement")' target="_blank" class="item active">
    <img src="~/Images/adv1.png" alt="1">
</a>
```

You can still make it appear as a block-level element like the `div` with some simple CSS:

```
a.item {
    display:block
}
```